# How to get rid of floating texture in render?

Tags: rendering, texturing, objects, 3d-view

I am using the minecraft rig to make an animation. Whenever I render the image to see how it looks, there is a floating object next to my character that does not show up when I'm in 3D view. I don't know why its there and I need help to get rid of it.
I have no idea how to get rid of it, I cant select it either.

[image: The glitch object is next to the tree]

Comment: And I have no idea what object you are talking about. However try pressing `Alt H` in the 3D view.

Comment: its still not working, the floating thing is yellow and red and is next to the tree

Comment: You need to give us a lead. Go look on the list of objects on the top right, including their hierarchies and see if anything is disabled from selection or disabled from being viewable.

Comment: Asking "what is this thing in my .blend?!" is like showing us a picture you took with a blurry object in front of your camera and asking us "what is this thing in my photo?!" Without seeing the scene it's really hard to guess, so please upload your .blend.

Comment: A month later and it actually works. Thx David, your a genius. I changed the settings because I don't have numpad keys in my keyboard because I have an Imac, and now it works, thanks again so much!